# List of books used by veterinarians from the first day of training to the last

Tags: health

I have grown dogs from puppies and learned by experience and minor sources... Now I would be interested in having a look at the same books used by veterinarians in their school. I've noticed that, for the most part, they have standardized procedures worldwide.

Comment: Textbooks are chosen by professors, so they're going to be different based on the professor. Courses also vary from school to school. So you're not going to have a set list of books.

Comment: I think that the "standardized" part of my post made someone upset.

Answer (score 1):

This answers is not meant at telling you how to become a vet in 7 days, but in cases I want "professional" grade information or access scientifically reviewed studies, I would go like this:

- Find the webpage of your local vet school, figure how what are the required courses and in what order, go to these courses websites and find out what's the main textbook.
- There is a long list of veterinary medicine/veterinary behavioural medicine worldwide. [Elsevier](http://www.elsevier.com) publishes a bunch of major ones, eg. [Applied Animal Behaviour Science](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/applied-animal-behaviour-science/) and [Journal of Veterinary Behavior: Clinical Applications and Research](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/journal-of-veterinary-behavior-clinical-applications-and-research/). Most of them are not (entirely) free and the online access platform of Elsevier is [ScienceDirect](http://www.sciencedirect.com).

Again this is not meant to promote self learning or self practice of veterinary medicine.

Comment: I do not intend to become a vet... I am interested in acquiring the knowledge.

Comment: Good, that's exactly what my answer is about ;)